# Struggling with Algorithmic Inequalities - Seeking Insights and Feedback on Approach!

Tags: asymptotics

Hello everyone I don't really understand the question.

I approached the given problem by carefully examining the provided sequence of inequalities, aiming to understand the growth rates of various functions. Breaking down the given function (f(n) = 9n^n + 8n! + \sqrt{5n} + n \log_4(n)), I compared each term against the established inequalities. I successfully identified the dominant terms as (n^n) and (n!), and through subsequent analysis, determined that (n^n) dominates over (n!). Utilizing the given inequalities, particularly (n^n > n!), I concluded that the closest upper boundary for (f(n)) is (O(9n^n)). While I feel confident in this assessment, there might be additional nuances or insights to consider, and I would appreciate any feedback or further discussion on the approach I've taken.

**1 < log<sub>2</sub>(n) < √n < n <nlog<sub>2</sub>(n) < n<sup>2</sup> < n<sup>3</sup> < … < 2<sup>n</sup> < n! < n<sup>n</sup>**

Use the inequalities above to find the closest upper boundary function for

**f(n)=9n<sup>n</sup> + 8n! + sqrt(5n) + nlog<sub>4</sub>(n)**

the **answers** as follows

**n<sup>n</sup>**

1

n<sup>2</sup>

n<sup>4</sup>

n<sup>3</sup>

log<sub>4</sub>(n)

n!

*n* log<sub>4</sub>(n)

n

2<sup>n</sup>

√n

n<sup>5</sup>